# Bluetooth scan methods - PendingIntent or ScanCallback?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon

my application scans BLE devices in background.
I don't understand what determines the choice between these two methods:
advantage / disadvantage. (I tested both and it works)

```
public int startScan (List<ScanFilter> filters, 
            ScanSettings settings, 
            PendingIntent callbackIntent)

public void startScan (List<ScanFilter> filters, 
                ScanSettings settings, 
                ScanCallback callback)`
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android 8+ allows you to deliver Bluetooth scan results with two different messaging transports: Callback and Intent.

**Callback**

This makes a call to a method you define with the scan results.

Pros:

- Simpler setup in code
- Lighter weight (less CPU usage) due to no need to serialize scan result data structures.  This is especially important if you expect a heavy volume of detections.
- Works on older Android versions, not just 8+

Cons:

- Background scans are generally limited to 10 minutes at a time unless you start a Foreground Service to keep your app running in the background.
- Cannot re-launch your app in the background on detection

**Intent**

This delivers the scan results to a BroadcastReceiver using Android’s Intent messaging structure

Pros:

- Delivers results in the background indefinitely without a Foreground Service
- Can re-launch your app on detection

Cons:

- Higher power usage, especially with heavy scan results
- More complex code setup
- Does not work before Android 8
- Scans to detect pattern match loss will be missed if Android Doze mode has kicked in
- Processing scan results at regular intervals (if needed) still requires timers and perhaps a Foreground Service, negating many of the Pros

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify one thing: when scanning using PendingIntent, should we stop scanning by calling stopScan(sameIntent) when the device of interest is found?

Comment: Yes, if you do not need more results you should stop scanning to save battery.